# AttributeError: 'ArabertPreprocessor' object has no attribute 'farasa_segmenter'

Tags: python, nlp, google-colaboratory, arabic

I had this error while using AraBERT,

```
from arabert.preprocess import ArabertPreprocessor

model_name = "bert-base-arabertv2"
arabert_prep = ArabertPreprocessor(model_name=model_name, keep_emojis=False)

text = "ولن نبالغ إذا قلنا إن هاتف أو كمبيوتر المكتب في زمننا هذا ضروري"
arabert_prep.preprocess(text)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It might be that `farasapy` is required as per the [docs](https://github.com/aub-mind/arabert#preprocessing), so try to install first.

> It is recommended to apply our preprocessing function before training/testing on any dataset. Install farasapy to segment text for AraBERT v1 & v2 pip install farasapy